# Abstract way to create an illegal parameter class for unit testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

The data fields of our column based database are mapped into a DataField class. On each data field object the `GetValue<T>()` method can be invoked.

If `T` is an illegal type an exception gets thrown. What type should I pass in my unit test, where I test if an exception gets thrown if I pass an illegal type? The next known illegal type which comes in my mind? Or is there an approach with some more abstraction?

```
public object GetValue<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) return ValueString;
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int?)) return ValueInt;
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(double?)) return ValueDouble;
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime?)) return ValueDateTime;
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool)) return ValueBoolean == true;

    var ex = new Exception("Following type is not supported: " + typeof(T));
    Log.Error(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

So every type but those should throw this exception if they get passed. So I'd need a kind of dummy type, right?

At the moment my unit test looks like this:

```
[Fact]
public void If_T_is_illegal_type_an_exception_gets_thrown()
{
    _dataField = new DataField(_params);
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => _dataField.GetValue<Type>());
}
```

Comment: What would an example of an illegal type be? Done correctly this can be caught by the compiler and not unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that unit testing is trying to get through all code paths and ensuring correct behaviour. You should have 6 tests in total: one for each of the 5 valid types, and one with **any other type** (as you currently have) to cover the final code path. Not sure why you'd need something more abstract.

You may prefer to use explicit conversions and casting so that this becomes a compile time test rather than run time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Okay. I just thought there was kind of a standard or default, given type which stands for *"any other type"*. Explicit conversion look very nice. Though we cast these objects like this in another generic method: `(T)_dataField.GetValue<T>()`. But explicit conversion doesn't work with `T`, because it's not a compile time constant, right?

Answer (score 0):

Currently if you call `GetValue<bool>()` your code will call `typeof(T)` five times and make 5 comparisons. Then it will return boxed boolean value as object. And the worst thing is that signature of this method says nothing about which types are allowed and which will throw exception. Can I call `GetValue<decimal>()`? Don't know. I should try and have runtime exception if it is not allowed.

Consider creating overloaded methods for required types:

```
bool GetBooleanValue()
decimal GetDecimalValue()
```

This describes perfectly what types it could return. There are no long if chain inside. Caller will not receive objects. And you will have test for each of this methods without questions.

Comment: That doesn't fit for our project. We actually extract the data from our DataFields to OurUIDataFields. The OurUIDataFields class is generic. If I'd create overloads I would need a switch over T to call the different get-methods. I think a refactoring of our DataFields to a generic class would be the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, one test for each supported type and one for a non-supported type should suffice.

The one thing I do note though is that the exception is not the only expected result for the error. How are you verifying that the error is logged?
Do you have a way of doing this?
If not, do you want/need one?

Also, a totally unsolicited code review point...  why

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool)) return ValueBoolean == true;
```

instead of

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool)) return ValueBoolean;
```

Alan.

Comment: I create a Mock of the static logger in my DataField class. When `Log.Error()` gets invoked I catch this invocation and set a bool `errorFired` variable in my unit test. `return ValueBoolean == true`: I have recognized this either. This kind of code gets removed via ReSharper, usually.

Comment: Sounds good. It wasn't being checked in the example code so I thought I'd mention it.